# efficient comparator for an std::map with a struct key

Tags: c++, dictionary, comparator, predicate, stdmap

I have a struct of following type which I am planning use as a key in a map. 
Hence I write a comparator like below. I would like to know if there is a more elegant yet efficient way of doing this.
May be using `std::pair` or something.

```
struct T 
{
  int a, b, c, d;

  bool operator< (const T& r) {
    if (a < r.a)
       return true
    else if (a == r.a)
       if (b < r.b)
          return true;
       else if (b == r.b)
            if (c < r.c) 
                return true;
            else if (c == r.c)
                if (d < r.d)
                   return true;
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you use C++11? If so:

```
struct T {
    int a, b, c, d;

    bool operator<(const T& rhs) const {
        return tied() < rhs.tied();
    }

private:
    std::tuple<int, int, int, int> tied() const {
        return std::make_tuple(a, b, c, d);
    }
};
```

Alternatively, I would prefer `return`ing at each possible opportunity to avoid the error-prone awkward nesting approach:

```
bool operator<(const T& rhs) const {
    if (a != rhs.a) return a < rhs.a;
    if (b != rhs.b) return b < rhs.b;
    if (c != rhs.c) return c < rhs.c;
    return d < rhs.d;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately no c++11

Answer (score 0):

You can use...

```
bool operator<(const T& r)
{
    return a < r.a ||
           a == r.a && (b < r.b || 
                        b == r.b && (c < r.c || 
                                     c == r.c && d < r.d));
}
```

Or...

```
    return a != r.a ? a < r.a :
           b != r.b ? b < r.b :
           c != r.c ? c < r.c :
                      d < r.d;
```

---

You've said you're not using C++11, and Barry has a good illustration of a tuple approach, but for future reference and other interested parties, with a little reusable support code...

```
bool less_by_pairs()
{
    return false;
}

template <typename T, typename U, typename ...Args>
bool less_by_pairs(const T& v1, const U& v2, Args... args)
{
    return v1 != v2 ? v1 < v2 : less_by_pairs(args...);
}
```

...you can implement such operators more easily...

```
bool operator<(const T& r)
{
    return less_by_pairs(a, r.a, b, r.b, c, r.c, d, r.d);
}
```

You could do something similar providing a list of members to compare, but the notation for that's actually a little verbose anyway.

Answer (score -1):

You could use another field to store a key. This key value could be generated through a formula, that takes as input `(a,b,c,d)`

Like so:

```
void hash()
{
    key = (a ^ b ^ c ^ d);
}
```

As result, you would need to only compare this key to know if the contents are the same.

Comment: This is a `std::map`, we need to put values in sorted order. This would not differentiate `(0,0,0,1)` from `(1,0,0,0)`.